# How to run 1000 user concurrently using Jmeter and Selenium Webdriver in Junit without causing PC to hang?

Tags: selenium, jmeter, nunit

I try to run 10 user accessing a website concurrency by using Selenium Webdriver in JUnit and it caused my PC to lag because it open 10 Browser at the same time. I even tried to run Jmeter in Command Prompt, it is just laggy. Is there any methods to actually run 1000 user concurrently without stressing my PC?

Comment: You could take a look at 'selenium grid' to off-load browsers to other computers, however, it will require a lot of network traffic so likely your test wont behave as you hope.
I'd consider running concurrency tests against the APIs, rather than the UI

Comment: @SirLenz0rlot i was thinking bout Selenium Grid as well, because it is able to run on multiple pc.

Answer (score 2):

Each browser has its system requirements, for example for [Firefox 71](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/71.0/system-requirements/) they are:

- 512MB of RAM / 2GB of RAM for the 64-bit version
- Pentium 4 or newer processor that supports SSE2

If you want to kick off several browsers - you need to have:

1. 2 GB of RAM per browser instance
2. 1 CPU core per browser instance

For 10 browsers you will need to have 11+ CPU cores and 22+ GB of RAM, for 1000 browsers - proportionally more.

If you **have to** conduct performance testing using real browsers you will need to go for [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) and allocate sufficient amount of machines to act as load generators. Remember that machines must not be overloaded as if they will not be able to operate fast enough - you won't get accurate results.

Another option is migrating your Selenium tests to JMeter, you can basically [run your Selenium tests through JMeter proxy](https://help.crossbrowsertesting.com/selenium-testing/faq/selenium-testing-proxy/) so JMeter will be able to capture the relevant [HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) and convert them into [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers or replay them via [Proxy2JMX Converter](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Proxy2JMX/#Proxy2JMX-Converter) module of [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool, check out [How to Convert Selenium Scripts into the JMX](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter/) article for more details.

JMeter's HTTP Request samplers have very small footprint comparing to real browsers so you will be able to mimic several thousands of virtual users from a modern mid-range laptop given you follow JMeter Best Practices

Comment: Hmm, I regularly do 25+ browsers on my 4 core/16GB ram laptop without problems. I agree that 1000 would require a beastly machine though.

Comment: I had done some researches and saw some of tester used PAID cloud-based load testing to perform load test/performance test. But once again thanks for the advice.